# How do I get a value from this dictionary in my HTML template?

Tags: python, html, django

```
def playerData(request, player_id):
    r = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/players/" + str(player_id) +"/matches/?limit=20")
    last20matches = json.loads(r.text)

    return render (request, "playerstats.jinja", {'last20' : last20matches,'playerid' : player_id})
```

```
{% for entry in last20 %}
    <li>

        <a href= "https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/"> {% entry["match_id"] %}  </a>

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

so in my playerData function I get a players last 20 matches and set it to r.

last20matches is a list of 20 dictionaries.

Now to the template. 
I'm going through every dictionary ( each dictionary is a match ) and I want to create a link to a page (https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/match_id).

However, the match_id is in the dictionary with key match_id. How do I get this into my link in the html file?

Error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 20: 'entry["match_id"]', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Comment: Sorry. Thought the images would show up. Updated

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I know you've edited the code in, but it never hurts to explain the rules

Comment: yeah , I understand sorry.

Comment: Try `entry.match_id` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work. these are the dict keys
```
dict_keys(['match_id', 'player_slot', 'radiant_win', 'duration', 'game_mode', 'lobby_type', 'hero_id', 'start_time', 'version', 'kills', 'deaths', 'assists', 'skill', 'leaver_status', 'party_size'])
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the output of `print(last20matches)`.  Also, "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.  What does it do?  Do you get an error message?  Does it just print a blank space?

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes. Firstly, variables are always denoted by `{{ ... }}`, not `{% ... %}` which is for tags. Secondly, all lookups - including dictionaries - in a Django template are done via dot notation, not square brackets.

So:

```
<a href= "https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/"> {{ entry.match_id }}  </a>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. That did solve my problem.

I understnad the variables are denoted by {{ ... }} now but I thought that I needed to use {% ... %} to invoke python code.

So I thought I'd have to use

`{% {{entry}}["match_id"] %}`


Could you explain why this doesn't work and why the method you described does?

Comment: I can't understand why you would think you need any of that. Why should it work? There is no concept of "invoking Python code" in a template.

Comment: {% for entry in last20 %}
  
{% endfor %}

I'm new to django but I was under the impression there is no real code in html files and the only way I can make this for loop is by bringing python code into it. Is that wrong?

Comment: {% for %} is a special template tag. Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/) for a list of built-in template tags. Anything else you put in {% ... %} needs to be a template tag you define yourself. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) is a guide to create your custom tags. As @DanielRoseman said you can't "invoke python code" in a template.